# CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData function not recognized in Xcode IOS

Tags: ios, swift, cfdata

I am looking at a camera tutorial for IOS and the `CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData` function was used.  However Xcode doesn't seem to recognize it.  Was this function removed from the latest Xcode Swift update?  I am using Xcode version 8.1 and Swift 3.  Also I have the following imports:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried searching "CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData" in the Apple's [API reference page](https://developer.apple.com/reference/)?

When I tried, I was guided to the [Objective-C page](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/1408284-cgdataprovidercreatewithcfdata), and its [Swift link](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgdataprovider/1408284-init) shows:

> Initializer
>
> ```
> init(data:)
> ```
>
> Creates a data provider that reads from a CFData object.

In Swift 3, `CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData` is imported as an initializer of `CGDataProvider` and use it as:

```
let dataProvider = CGDataProvider(data: imageData as CFData)
```

(Assuming `imageData` as a `Data`.)

You can use it with `import UIKit`.